# In Spring batch xml writing can we write complex xml for specific nos of records

Tags: xml, spring-batch, filesize, xmlwriter

I have to design a spring batch job which reads from database (suppose JdbcCursorItemReader) and write the data in to XML (complex xml as shown below).
I have following queries.
a). XML should not exceed more than 8k records. If there are more records, a new XML to be written.
For e.g.
There are 10K records fetched from the database.
REQ_1.xml -> 8k records
REQ_2.xml -> 2k records

b). How can I dynamically attach the Header block (header & summary) while writing the XML for both xml.

Thanks in advance.

The xml structure is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faxml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ST_BD0.xsd">
    <header>
        <extsysname>CU</extsysname>
        <datpost>2013-04-20</datpost>
    </header>
    <summary>
        <countdr>4000</countdr>
        <countcr>4000</countcr>
        <sumdr>1600000.00</sumdr>
        <sumcr>1600000.00</sumcr>
    </summary>
    <txnlist>
        <txndata>
            <debit>
                <accountno>6000000000029</accountno>
                <amount>400.00</amount>
            </debit>
            <credit>
                <accountno>022222222222222</accountno>
                <amount>400.00</amount>
            </credit>
        </txndata>
        <txndata>
            <debit>
                <accountno>6000000000029</accountno>
                <amount>400.00</amount>
            </debit>
            <credit>
                <accountno>022222222222222</accountno>
                <amount>400.00</amount>
            </credit>
        </txndata>
    </txnlist>
</faxml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [MultiResourceItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemWriter.html) for that and set the `itemCountLimitPerResource` to 8000. You can also customize the suffix to be `_1`, `_2`, etc using a custom `ResourceSuffixCreator`.

Comment: Thanks Ben, it did work for creating multiple files using MultiResourceItemWriter but I could not understand the relation between chunks and setItemCountLimitPerResource.

For e.g If my job has 100 chunks size and I need to create max of 8000 records in a single file. 
Will this create a second file post 8000 records, even if chunk size is 100 or 8000.
As I'm new to spring hence could not able to get this.

Also, could you highlight any reference for point B as well. I tried attaching the static header using setHeaderCallback, but I need to attach the dynamic header.